# CvStereoCalibrate (CvLevMarq::updateAlt()) takes an infinite amount of time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, levenberg-marquardt

I have some problem. I tries to calibrate my cameras. I wrote some function to do this but it took some strange data, so I try to check it with example from O'Reilly OpenCV book (there is an example 12-3 from chapter 12: Projection and 3D Vision).
I adjust that example to my program but program hangs (if it is good word). I checked deeper in opencv's functions and discovered that in cvStereoCalibrate there is cvCalibrateCamera2 that contains problem: during optimization part the line:

```
bool proceed = solver.updateAlt( _param, _JtJ, _JtErr, _errNorm ); //solver is object of CvLevMarq
```

takes very long (infinity) time.

Why it takes so long (many hours)? Or maybe I made some mistake but I don't know where (I rewrite it from the book, maybe wrong)

Here is my code:

```
void Calibration::stereoCalibTest()
{
  int displayCorners = 0;
  int showUndistorted = 1;
  bool isVerticalStereo = false;
  const int maxScale = 1;
  const float squareSize = m_squareSize;
  int nframes, n = m_boardSize.width() * m_boardSize.height(), N = 0;
  int nx = m_boardSize.width();
  int ny = m_boardSize.height();

  vector<CvPoint3D32f> objectPoints;
  vector<CvPoint2D32f> points[2];
  vector<int> npoints;
  vector<CvPoint2D32f> temp(n);
  vector<uchar> active[2];

  CvSize imageSize = {0,0};

  //ARRAY AND VECTOR STORAGE
  double M1[3][3], M2[3][3], D1[5], D2[5];
  double R[3][3], T[3], E[3][3], F[3][3];
  CvMat _M1 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, M1);
  CvMat _M2 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, M2);
  CvMat _D1 = cvMat(1, 5, CV_64F, D1);
  CvMat _D2 = cvMat(1, 5, CV_64F, D2);
  CvMat _R = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, R);
  CvMat _T = cvMat(3, 1, CV_64F, T);
  CvMat _E = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, E);
  CvMat _F = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, F);

  //FOR LEFT CAMERA

  for(int  i = 0; i < m_imageList1.size(); i++)
  {
    IplImage *im_gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(m_imageList1[i]),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
    cvCvtColor(m_imageList1[i],im_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);

    vector<CvPoint2D32f> &pts = points[0];
    int count = 0, result = 0;
    imageSize = cvGetSize(m_imageList1[i]);
    result = cvFindChessboardCorners(im_gray, cvSize(nx, ny), &temp[0], &count, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);

    N = pts.size();
    pts.resize(N + n, cvPoint2D32f(0,0));
    active[0].push_back((uchar)result);

    if(result)
    {
      cvFindCornerSubPix(im_gray, &temp[0], count, cvSize(11, 11), cvSize(-1, -1), cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER + CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 30, 0.01));
      copy(temp.begin(), temp.end(), pts.begin()+N);
    }

  }

  //FOR RIGHT CAMERA

  for(int  i = 0; i < m_imageList2.size(); i++)
  {
    vector<CvPoint2D32f> &pts = points[1];
    int count = 0, result = 0;
    imageSize = cvGetSize(m_imageList2[i]);
    IplImage *im_gray = cvCreateImage(imageSize,IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
    cvCvtColor(m_imageList2[i],im_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);
    result = cvFindChessboardCorners(im_gray, cvSize(nx, ny), &temp[0], &count, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);

    N = pts.size();
    pts.resize(N + n, cvPoint2D32f(0,0));
    active[0].push_back((uchar)result);

    if(result)
    {
      cvFindCornerSubPix(im_gray, &temp[0], count, cvSize(11, 11), cvSize(-1, -1), cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER + CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 30, 0.01));
      copy(temp.begin(), temp.end(), pts.begin()+N);
    }
  }

  // HARVEST CHESSBOARD 3D OBJECT POINT LIST:

  nframes = active[0].size();
  objectPoints.resize(nframes * n);
  for(int i = 0; i < ny; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < nx; j++)
      objectPoints[i * nx + j] = cvPoint3D32f(i*squareSize, j*squareSize, 0);

  for(int i = 1; i < nframes; i++)
    copy(objectPoints.begin(), objectPoints.begin() + n, objectPoints.begin() + i *n);
  npoints.resize(nframes, n);
  N = nframes * n;
  CvMat _objectPoints = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC3, &objectPoints[0]);
  CvMat _imagePoints1 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC2, &points[0][0]);
  CvMat _imagePoints2 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC2, &points[1][0]);
  CvMat _npoints  = cvMat(1, npoints.size(), CV_32S, &npoints[0]);
  cvSetIdentity(&_M1);
  cvSetIdentity(&_M2);
  cvZero(&_D1);
  cvZero(&_D2);

  //CALIBRATE THE STEREO CAMERAS
  ui.teInfo->append("Calibrating from TEST FUNCTION");

  cvStereoCalibrate(&_objectPoints, &_imagePoints1, &_imagePoints2, &_npoints, &_M1, &_D1, &_M2, &_D2, imageSize, &_R, &_T, &_E, &_F, cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER + CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5), CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO + CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST + CV_CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH);

  ui.teInfo->append("Done!");


  // CALIBRATION QUALITY CHECK
  // because the output fundamental matrix implicitly
  // includes all the output information,
  // we can check the quality of calibration using the
  // epipolar geometry constraint: m2^t * F * m1 = 0

  vector<CvPoint3D32f> lines[2];
  points[0].resize(N);
  points[1].resize(N);
  _imagePoints1 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC2, &points[0][0]);
  _imagePoints2 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC2, &points[1][0]);

  lines[0].resize(N);
  lines[1].resize(N);
  CvMat _L1 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC3, &lines[0][0]);
  CvMat _L2 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC3, &lines[1][0]);

  // Always work in undistorted space
  cvUndistortPoints(&_imagePoints1, &_imagePoints1, &_M1, &_D1, 0, &_M1);
  cvUndistortPoints(&_imagePoints2, &_imagePoints2, &_M2, &_D2, 0, &_M2);

  cvComputeCorrespondEpilines(&_imagePoints1, 1, &_F, &_L1);
  cvComputeCorrespondEpilines(&_imagePoints2, 2, &_F, &_L2);
  double avgErr = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    double err = fabs(points[0][i].x*lines[1][i].x + 
      points[0][i].y*lines[1][i].y + lines[1][i].z) +
      fabs(points[1][i].x*lines[0][i].x + points[1][i].y*lines[0][i].y + lines[0][i].z);
    avgErr += err;
  }

  ui.teInfo->append("average error: " +QString::number(avgErr/(nframes*n)));

  double R1[3][3], R2[3][3], P1[3][4], P2[3][4];
  CvMat _R1 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, R1);
  CvMat _R2 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, R2);
  CvMat _P1 = cvMat(3, 4, CV_64F, P1);
  CvMat _P2 = cvMat(3, 4, CV_64F, P2);

  cvStereoRectify(&_M1, &_M2, &_D1, &_D2, imageSize, &_R, &_T, 
    &_R1, &_R2, &_P1, &_P2, 0,0);

  ui.teInfo->append("TEST: cameras calibrated");
  bool isSaved = saveToFile(&_M1, &_M2, &_D1, &_D2, &_R1, &_R2, &_P1, &_P2);
  if(isSaved)
    ui.teInfo->append("TEST: saved to file");
  else
    ui.teInfo->append("TEST: cannot save to file");
}
```

takes very long time

Comment: It should not take long time.
The time is depend on number of images.
Which version of OpenCV you use?
You can find the full detailed of Camera Calibration based on OpenCV 3.x in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWOL8yXL6xI) and [this based on OpenCV 3.1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFUiDZ82tBY)

Comment: I take 50 images per camera. I use opencv in version 2.4.0 (I can't use newer because I use other libraries that can't work with newer version of opencv). Additionaly I work with Qt library to create GUI.